# Build jar library with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My question is, can I use Xamarin to write business logic and compile it as a JAR library and use it in Android Studio ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that Xamarin platform just work by c#

> form Xamarin Site:
>
> If you are a Java developer, you are well on your way to leveraging
>   your skills and existing code on the Xamarin platform while reaping
>   the code reuse benefits of C#. You will find that C# syntax is very
>   similar to Java syntax, and that both languages provide very similar
>   features. In addition, you'll discover features unique to C# that will
>   make your development life easier.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/

Comment: Ok thank you! I read this article, just wondering if there is a way that I didn't find at the first search